# Encountered errors when trying to set up the OAuth 2.0 endpoint on my dynamic CRM 2015 internet facing deployment hosted on ADFS 3.0?

Tags: authentication, oauth, dynamics-crm, adfs3.0

I am following the [guidelines](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg188602.aspx) described in msdn website  to set up the dynamic CRM server 2015 in my local domain, everything works as expected.

But I have some problems accessing my server with OAuth 2.0 authentication. From the official [document](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn531009.aspx), OAuth authentication is supported by dynamic CRM.

> Developers who create modern and mobile apps, including apps not
>   built on the .NET Framework, can access Microsoft Dynamics CRM
>   business data through the SOAP and OData endpoints of the organization
>   web service. This web service supports certain authentication
>   capabilities found in the OAuth 2.0 protocol.

However when I am following the [link](https://github.com/nordvall/TokenClient/wiki/OAuth-2-Authorization-Code-grant-in-ADFS) to perform the OAuth flow, I get the below error message information in AD FS event log when trying to get the access token.

> Encountered error during federation passive request.  Exception
>   details:  Microsoft.IdentityServer.RequestFailedException: MSIS7065:
>   There are no registered protocol handlers on path /adfs/oauth2/token
>   to process the incoming request.    at
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.PassiveProtocolListener.OnGetContext(WrappedHttpListenerContext
>   context)

I've already added the OAuth 2.0 application into my CRM server. My question is which steps do I missed to make the OAuth authentication works?

**Updated [11/11/2015]:**
It turn out to me that there might be some configuration errors when I used postman do the token acquisition operation. I used PowerShell and it works. Shared my command below:

```
$nvc = New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.NameValueCollection
$nvc.Add("client_id", "you client id")
$nvc.Add("grant_type", "authorization_code")
$nvc.Add("code", "authorization code")
$nvc.Add("redirect_uri", "your redirect uri")
$wc = new-object net.webclient
$response = $wc.UploadValues("https://your.adfs.server/adfs/oauth2/token", "POST", $nvc)
$tokens = $wc.Encoding.GetString($response);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same exact error while using postman.  I just forgot to use x-www-form-urlencoded.  Then it worked nicely.